# How to retreive data from web analytics using console application?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-analytics, console-application

I have a sharepoint site where where i have web analytics service started. I will get a rrport denoting the no of visits by the user and also below i have last modified date and no of visits by all users in that site? I need to retreive the last modified date and no of visits by the user using console application. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I came across this today: http://otak-otak-it.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-get-sharepoint-2010-web.html

The article explains how to pull Web Analytics data from SQL Server. While that does not get the data to the console, it may be useful in developing a solution that does; a powershell script perhaps.